# Select primary image by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery image uploader, made by Christian Bayer. You can check it out here: https://github.com/christianbayer/image-uploader

With Swati's help, I modified it a little bit, so I can select the primary image by clicking on the preview of the image. I'd like to add one more function, which should automatically select the first image as the primary image if the user doesn't pick one.
For example, the user selects these images from their pc:

```
example1.jpg, example2.jpg, example3.png
```

In this case, example1.jpg would be selected automatically. I use onclick event to select the primary image, but no idea where and what should I write to be auto selected.

Here's the working example. You can try this by clicking on an image.

```js
(function($) {

    $.fn.imageUploader = function(options) {
        let defaults = {
            preloaded: [],
            imagesInputName: 'images',
            preloadedInputName: 'preloaded',
            label: 'Drag & Drop files here or click to browse',
            extensions: ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', '.svg'],
            mimes: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/svg+xml'],
            maxSize: undefined,
            maxFiles: undefined,
        };
        let plugin = this;
        let dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

        // The file input
        let $input;

        // Set empty settings
        plugin.settings = {};

        // Plugin constructor
        plugin.init = function() {

            // Define settings
            plugin.settings = $.extend(plugin.settings, defaults, options);

            // Run through the elements
            plugin.each(function(i, wrapper) {

                // Create the container
                let $container = createContainer();

                // Append the container to the wrapper
                $(wrapper).append($container);

                // Set some bindings
                $container.on("dragover", fileDragHover.bind($container));
                $container.on("dragleave", fileDragHover.bind($container));
                $container.on("drop", fileSelectHandler.bind($container));

                // If there are preloaded images
                if (plugin.settings.preloaded.length) {

                    // Change style
                    $container.addClass('has-files');

                    // Get the upload images container
                    let $uploadedContainer = $container.find('.uploaded');

                    // Set preloaded images preview
                    for (let i = 0; i < plugin.settings.preloaded.length; i++) {
                        $uploadedContainer.append(createImg(plugin.settings.preloaded[i].src, plugin.settings.preloaded[i].id, true));
                    }

                }

            });

        };

        let createContainer = function() {

            // Create the image uploader container
            let $container = $('<div>', {
                class: 'image-uploader'
            });

            // Create the input type file and append it to the container
            $input = $('<input>', {
                type: 'file',
                id: plugin.settings.imagesInputName + '-' + random(),
                name: plugin.settings.imagesInputName + '[]',
                accept: plugin.settings.extensions.join(','),
                multiple: ''
            }).appendTo($container);

            // Create the uploaded images container and append it to the container
            let $uploadedContainer = $('<div>', {
                    class: 'uploaded'
                }).appendTo($container),

                // Create the text container and append it to the container
                $textContainer = $('<div>', {
                    class: 'upload-text'
                }).appendTo($container),

                // Create the icon and append it to the text container
                $i = $('<i>', {
                    class: 'iui-cloud-upload'
                }).appendTo($textContainer),

                // Create the text and append it to the text container
                $span = $('<span>', {
                    text: plugin.settings.label
                }).appendTo($textContainer);


            // Listen to container click and trigger input file click
            $container.on('click', function(e) {
                // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
                prevent(e);

                // Trigger input click
                $input.trigger('click');
            });

            // Stop propagation on input click
            $input.on("click", function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

            // Listen to input files changed
            $input.on('change', fileSelectHandler.bind($container));

            return $container;
        };


        let prevent = function(e) {
            // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        };

        let createImg = function(src, id, preloaded) {

            // Create the upladed image container
            let $container = $('<div>', {
                    class: 'uploaded-image'
                }),

                // Create the img tag
                $img = $('<img>', {
                    src: src
                }).appendTo($container),

                // Create the delete button
                $button = $('<button>', {
                    class: 'delete-image'
                }).appendTo($container),

                // Create the delete icon
                $i = $('<i>', {
                    class: 'iui-close'
                }).appendTo($button);


            // If the image is preloaded
            if (preloaded) {

                // Set a identifier
                $container.attr('data-preloaded', true);

                // Create the preloaded input and append it to the container
                let $preloaded = $('<input>', {
                    type: 'hidden',
                    name: plugin.settings.preloadedInputName + '[]',
                    value: id
                }).appendTo($container)

            } else {

                // Set the index
                $container.attr('data-index', id);
                $container.attr('id', 'image-' + id);

            }

            //**** on click of image...***//
            $container.on("click", function(e) {
                var fi = $("input[type=file]")[0];
                prevent(e);
                console.log($(this).data('index'))
                console.log(fi.files.item($(this).data('index')).name);
                var main = fi.files.item($(this).data('index')).name;
                $(".uploaded-image").removeClass('main');
                $(this).addClass('main');
                //**get files using index (0,1,2..) add value to input..**//
                $("#mainimage").val(fi.files.item($(this).data('index')).name)
            });


            // Set delete action
            $button.on("click", function(e) {

                // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
                prevent(e);

                // Get the parent element
                let $parent = $container.parent();

                // If is not a preloaded image
                if ($container.data('preloaded') === true) {

                    // Remove from preloaded array
                    plugin.settings.preloaded = plugin.settings.preloaded.filter(function(p) {
                        return p.id !== id;
                    });

                } else {

                    // Get the image index
                    let index = parseInt($container.data('index'));

                    // Update other indexes
                    $parent.find('.uploaded-image[data-index]').each(function(i, cont) {
                        if (i > index) {
                            $(cont).attr('data-index', i - 1);
                        }
                    });

                    // Remove the file from input
                    dataTransfer.items.remove(index);

                    // Update input files
                    $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);
                }

                // Remove this image from the container
                $container.remove();

                // If there is no more uploaded files
                if (!$parent.children().length) {

                    // Remove the 'has-files' class
                    $parent.parent().removeClass('has-files');

                }

            });

            return $container;
        };

        let fileDragHover = function(e) {

            // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
            prevent(e);

            // Change the container style
            if (e.type === "dragover") {
                $(this).addClass('drag-over');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('drag-over');
            }
        };

        let fileSelectHandler = function(e) {

            // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
            prevent(e);

            // Get the jQuery element instance
            let $container = $(this);

            // Get the files as an array of files
            let files = Array.from(e.target.files || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);

            // Will keep only the valid files
            let validFiles = [];

            // Run through the files
            $(files).each(function(i, file) {
                // Run the validations
                if (plugin.settings.extensions && !validateExtension(file)) {
                    return;
                }
                if (plugin.settings.mimes && !validateMIME(file)) {
                    return;
                }
                if (plugin.settings.maxSize && !validateMaxSize(file)) {
                    return;
                }
                if (plugin.settings.maxFiles && !validateMaxFiles(validFiles.length, file)) {
                    return;
                }
                validFiles.push(file);
            });

            // If there is at least one valid file
            if (validFiles.length) {
                // Change the container style
                $container.removeClass('drag-over');

                // Makes the upload
                setPreview($container, validFiles);
            } else {

                // Update input files (it is now empty due to a default browser action)
                $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);

            }
        };

        let validateExtension = function(file) {

            if (plugin.settings.extensions.indexOf(file.name.replace(new RegExp('^.*\\.'), '.')) < 0) {
                alert(`The file "${file.name}" does not match with the accepted file extensions: "${plugin.settings.extensions.join('", "')}"`);

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        };

        let validateMIME = function(file) {

            if (plugin.settings.mimes.indexOf(file.type) < 0) {
                alert(`The file "${file.name}" does not match with the accepted mime types: "${plugin.settings.mimes.join('", "')}"`);

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        };

        let validateMaxSize = function(file) {

            if (file.size > plugin.settings.maxSize) {
                alert(`The file "${file.name}" exceeds the maximum size of ${plugin.settings.maxSize / 1024 / 1024}Mb`);

                return false;
            }

            return true;

        };

        let validateMaxFiles = function(index, file) {

            if ((index + dataTransfer.items.length + plugin.settings.preloaded.length) >= plugin.settings.maxFiles) {
                alert(`The file "${file.name}" could not be added because the limit of ${plugin.settings.maxFiles} files was reached`);

                return false;
            }

            return true;

        };

        let setPreview = function($container, files) {

            // Add the 'has-files' class
            $container.addClass('has-files');

            // Get the upload images container
            let $uploadedContainer = $container.find('.uploaded'),

                // Get the files input
                $input = $container.find('input[type="file"]');

            // Run through the files
            $(files).each(function(i, file) {

                // Add it to data transfer
                dataTransfer.items.add(file);

                // Set preview
                $uploadedContainer.append(createImg(URL.createObjectURL(file), dataTransfer.items.length - 1), false);

            });

            // Update input files
            $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);

        };

        // Generate a random id
        let random = function() {
            return Date.now() + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        };

        this.init();

        // Return the instance
        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));
$('.input-images').imageUploader();
```

```css
.main {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="imgs">
<div class="input-images"></div>
```

The onclick event itself:

```
//**** on click of image...***//
$container.on("click", function(e) {
    var fi = $("input[type=file]")[0];
    prevent(e);
    console.log($(this).data('index'))
    console.log(fi.files.item($(this).data('index')).name);
    var main = fi.files.item($(this).data('index')).name;
    $(".uploaded-image").removeClass('main');
    $(this).addClass('main');
    //**get files using index (0,1,2..) add value to input..**//
    $("#mainimage").val(fi.files.item($(this).data('index')).name)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the `uploaded-image` div length is `> 0` then add class to first div using `:first`. i.e:

```
if($(".uploaded-image").length > 0){
    //add class to first one
    $(".uploaded-image:first").addClass("main")
    $("#imgs").val(fi.files.item(0).name)//add default name to imgs input
  }
```

***Demo Code*** :

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.imageUploader = function(options) {
    let defaults = {
      preloaded: [],
      imagesInputName: 'images',
      preloadedInputName: 'preloaded',
      label: 'Drag & Drop files here or click to browse',
      extensions: ['.jpg', '.JPG', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', '.svg', '.PNG'],
      mimes: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/svg+xml'],
      maxSize: undefined,
      maxFiles: undefined,
    };
    let plugin = this;
    let dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

    // The file input
    let $input;

    // Set empty settings
    plugin.settings = {};

    // Plugin constructor
    plugin.init = function() {

      // Define settings
      plugin.settings = $.extend(plugin.settings, defaults, options);

      // Run through the elements
      plugin.each(function(i, wrapper) {

        // Create the container
        let $container = createContainer();

        // Append the container to the wrapper
        $(wrapper).append($container);

        // Set some bindings
        $container.on("dragover", fileDragHover.bind($container));
        $container.on("dragleave", fileDragHover.bind($container));
        $container.on("drop", fileSelectHandler.bind($container));

        // If there are preloaded images
        if (plugin.settings.preloaded.length) {

          // Change style
          $container.addClass('has-files');

          // Get the upload images container
          let $uploadedContainer = $container.find('.uploaded');

          // Set preloaded images preview
          for (let i = 0; i < plugin.settings.preloaded.length; i++) {
            $uploadedContainer.append(createImg(plugin.settings.preloaded[i].src, plugin.settings.preloaded[i].id, true));
          }

        }

      });

    };

    let createContainer = function() {

      // Create the image uploader container
      let $container = $('<div>', {
        class: 'image-uploader'
      });

      // Create the input type file and append it to the container
      $input = $('<input>', {
        type: 'file',
        id: plugin.settings.imagesInputName + '-' + random(),
        name: plugin.settings.imagesInputName + '[]',
        accept: plugin.settings.extensions.join(','),
        multiple: ''
      }).appendTo($container);

      // Create the uploaded images container and append it to the container
      let $uploadedContainer = $('<div>', {
          class: 'uploaded'
        }).appendTo($container),

        // Create the text container and append it to the container
        $textContainer = $('<div>', {
          class: 'upload-text'
        }).appendTo($container),

        // Create the icon and append it to the text container
        $i = $('<i>', {
          class: 'iui-cloud-upload'
        }).appendTo($textContainer),

        // Create the text and append it to the text container
        $span = $('<span>', {
          text: plugin.settings.label
        }).appendTo($textContainer);


      // Listen to container click and trigger input file click
      $container.on('click', function(e) {
        // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
        prevent(e);

        // Trigger input click
        $input.trigger('click');
      });

      // Stop propagation on input click
      $input.on("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      });

      // Listen to input files changed
      $input.on('change', fileSelectHandler.bind($container));

      return $container;
    };


    let prevent = function(e) {
      // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    };

    let createImg = function(src, id, preloaded) {

      // Create the upladed image container
      let $container = $('<div>', {
          class: 'uploaded-image'
        }),

        // Create the img tag
        $img = $('<img>', {
          src: src
        }).appendTo($container),

        // Create the delete button
        $button = $('<button>', {
          class: 'delete-image'
        }).appendTo($container),

        // Create the delete icon
        $i = $('<i>', {
          class: 'iui-close'
        }).appendTo($button);


      // If the image is preloaded
      if (preloaded) {

        // Set a identifier
        $container.attr('data-preloaded', true);

        // Create the preloaded input and append it to the container
        let $preloaded = $('<input>', {
          type: 'hidden',
          name: plugin.settings.preloadedInputName + '[]',
          value: id
        }).appendTo($container)

      } else {

        // Set the index
        $container.attr('data-index', id);
        $container.attr('id', 'image-' + id);

      }

      //**** on click of image...***//
      $container.on("click", function(e) {
        var fi = $("input[type=file]")[0];
        prevent(e);
        var main = fi.files.item($(this).data('index')).name;
        $(".uploaded-image").removeClass('main');
        $(this).addClass('main');
        //**get files using index (0,1,2..) add value to input..**//
        $("#imgs").val(fi.files.item($(this).data('index')).name)
      });


      // Set delete action
      $button.on("click", function(e) {

        // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
        prevent(e);

        // Get the parent element
        let $parent = $container.parent();

        // If is not a preloaded image
        if ($container.data('preloaded') === true) {

          // Remove from preloaded array
          plugin.settings.preloaded = plugin.settings.preloaded.filter(function(p) {
            return p.id !== id;
          });

        } else {

          // Get the image index
          let index = parseInt($container.data('index'));

          // Update other indexes
          $parent.find('.uploaded-image[data-index]').each(function(i, cont) {
            if (i > index) {
              $(cont).attr('data-index', i - 1);
            }
          });

          // Remove the file from input
          dataTransfer.items.remove(index);

          // Update input files
          $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);

        }

        // Remove this image from the container
        $container.remove();

        // If there is no more uploaded files
        if (!$parent.children().length) {

          // Remove the 'has-files' class
          $parent.parent().removeClass('has-files');

        }
        refresh() //**call this**//
      });

      return $container;
    };

    let fileDragHover = function(e) {

      // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
      prevent(e);

      // Change the container style
      if (e.type === "dragover") {
        $(this).addClass('drag-over');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('drag-over');
      }
    };

    let fileSelectHandler = function(e) {

      // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
      prevent(e);

      // Get the jQuery element instance
      let $container = $(this);

      // Get the files as an array of files
      let files = Array.from(e.target.files || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);

      // Will keep only the valid files
      let validFiles = [];

      // Run through the files
      $(files).each(function(i, file) {
        // Run the validations
        if (plugin.settings.extensions && !validateExtension(file)) {
          return;
        }
        if (plugin.settings.mimes && !validateMIME(file)) {
          return;
        }
        if (plugin.settings.maxSize && !validateMaxSize(file)) {
          return;
        }
        if (plugin.settings.maxFiles && !validateMaxFiles(validFiles.length, file)) {
          return;
        }
        validFiles.push(file);
      });

      // If there is at least one valid file
      if (validFiles.length) {
        // Change the container style
        $container.removeClass('drag-over');

        // Makes the upload
        setPreview($container, validFiles);
      } else {

        // Update input files (it is now empty due to a default browser action)
        $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);

      }
    };

    let validateExtension = function(file) {

      if (plugin.settings.extensions.indexOf(file.name.replace(new RegExp('^.*\\.'), '.')) < 0) {
        alert(`The file "${file.name}" does not match with the accepted file extensions: "${plugin.settings.extensions.join('", "')}"`);

        return false;
      }

      return true;
    };

    let validateMIME = function(file) {

      if (plugin.settings.mimes.indexOf(file.type) < 0) {
        alert(`The file "${file.name}" does not match with the accepted mime types: "${plugin.settings.mimes.join('", "')}"`);

        return false;
      }

      return true;
    };

    let validateMaxSize = function(file) {

      if (file.size > plugin.settings.maxSize) {
        alert(`The file "${file.name}" exceeds the maximum size of ${plugin.settings.maxSize / 1024 / 1024}Mb`);

        return false;
      }

      return true;

    };

    let validateMaxFiles = function(index, file) {

      if ((index + dataTransfer.items.length + plugin.settings.preloaded.length) >= plugin.settings.maxFiles) {
        alert(`The file "${file.name}" could not be added because the limit of ${plugin.settings.maxFiles} files was reached`);

        return false;
      }

      return true;

    };

    let setPreview = function($container, files) {

      // Add the 'has-files' class
      $container.addClass('has-files');

      // Get the upload images container
      let $uploadedContainer = $container.find('.uploaded'),

        // Get the files input
        $input = $container.find('input[type="file"]');

      // Run through the files
      $(files).each(function(i, file) {

        // Add it to data transfer
        dataTransfer.items.add(file);

        // Set preview
        $uploadedContainer.append(createImg(URL.createObjectURL(file), dataTransfer.items.length - 1), false);

      });
      // Update input files
      $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);
      var fi = $("input[type=file]")[0];
      //**check if uploaded imag div is there **//
      if ($(".uploaded-image").length > 0) {
        //add class to first one
        $(".uploaded-image:first").addClass("main")
        $("#imgs").val(fi.files.item(0).name) //add default name to imgs input
      }
    };

    // Generate a random id
    let random = function() {
      return Date.now() + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    };

    this.init();

    // Return the instance
    return this;
  };
  let refresh = function() {
    var fi = $("input[type=file]")[0];
    if (($(".uploaded-image").length > 0) && ($(".main").length == 0)) {
      console.log("in")
      //add class to first one
      $(".uploaded-image:first").addClass("main")
      $("#imgs").val(fi.files.item(0).name) //add default name to imgs input
    }
    if ($(".uploaded-image").length == 0) {
      $("#imgs").val("")
    }

  }
}(jQuery));
$('.input-images').imageUploader();
```

```css
.main {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="imgs">
<div class="input-images"></div>
```

Comment: I just ran into a problem with this. If I delete the selected image, it's name doesn't disappear from the hidden input and it doesn't select the next one. Could you help me implement that please?

Comment: If I delete an image and trying to select another one, it throws this error: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null``` Not always, but sometimes. I think it's probably because of the data-index. Could you take a look at it please? I swear this is my last question :D

Comment: :P i am not seeing that error .. but if that's the issue then you can put some condition to check `if(fi.files.item(0).name != ""){ //add your input here }`  .Also , i am seeing some weird behaviour in this plugin.. sometimes it doesn't update total files values  i.e : click on delete button then `files  input value` doesn't get updated . :/

Comment: Could you suggest me another one with a good delete option where I can easily implement this primary image script?

Comment: Dropzone should work here is link  : https://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: Yes, I checked that but it looks like doesn't have the delete function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227758/discussion-between-swati-and-randomdude).